# Bottom border of table only shows on one column

Tags: tables

This table only has the bottom border on the last column in `tabular` and floating `table`.

I really don't know why.

Also I can't tell if this is the best way that I could have my text laid out.

```
\begin{table}[h]
    \small
    \noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{
        \begin{tabular}{|p{5cm}|p{1.4cm}|p{5cm}|p{1cm}|p{3.5cm}|}
            \hline

            More/Less(IV) of                           & Leads to    & More/Less of (DV)                                    & Due to & Reason                                                      \\
            \hline
            An increase in worldwide internet coverage & resulted in & an increase of video games with online functionality & due to & an increasing number of customers with internet connections
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    }
\end{table}
```

[image: The table]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Although it's almost always a good idea to include an example that can actually be compiled (i.e., it starts with `\documentclass` and proceeds through to `\end{document}`), there's enough information here to let you know that `\hline` should almost always follow `\\ `, that is, it should be on a new line.